# Square-Retrofit Response content type was not a proto (Protobuf)

Tags: java, android, protocol-buffers, retrofit

I'm trying to send post a request to the server, but I'm getting back a response

Caused by: retrofit.converter.ConversionException: Response content type was not a proto: application/x-protobuf;charset=UTF-8

I'm not sure if I've coded this wrong.

Interface RestInterface:

```
@Headers({"Accept: application/x-protobuf", "Content-Type: application/x-protobuf", "Authorization: Basic MTAyMTg3OjEwMjE4Nw=="})
@POST("/dashboard/mobile")
MobileDashboardResponse getQuotaGroupsByPublisher(@Body MobileDashboardRequest mobileDashboardRequest);
```

Adapter:

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
.setEndpoint(baseURL)
.setConverter(new ProtoConverter()).build();
```

Example usage

```
MobileDashboardRequest mobileDashboardRequest = MobileDashboardRequest.newBuilder()
    .setIpAddress("97.65.116.172")
    .setUserId(30002996)
    .build();
    MobileDashboardResponse mobileDashboardResponse = pfsRestApi.getQuotaGroupByPublisher(mobileDashboardRequest);

    System.out.println(mobileDashboardResponse);
```

When I send this request (Using TestNG) I'm getting a response of:
org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:212)

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with it.

retrofit.RetrofitError: Response content type was not a proto: application/json;charset=UTF-8

Comment: Did the error say application/json or application/x-protobuf (your question has both versions)? FWIW, application/x-protobuf with charset=UTF-8 makes no sense at all, since protobufs are not text.

Comment: I tried  both
application/json for accept/content-type... this threw an erro

So I tried
application/x-protobuf for accept/content-type